# how to specify a ruby version in my appspec file for aws codedeploy

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to deploy a ruby app to codedeploy and when it goes to install Sinatra it keeps giving me an error where it wants a higher version of ruby then installed on the server . How can i specify what version to use?

I have it specified in my Gemfile, have tried a few ways in the appspecfile

```
LifecycleEvent - BeforeInstall
Script - scripts/install_dependencies
[stdout]Successfully installed bundler-1.15.4
[stdout]Parsing documentation for bundler-1.15.4
[stdout]Done installing documentation for bundler after 5 seconds
[stdout]1 gem installed
[stdout]Updating installed gems
[stdout]Nothing to update
[stderr]ERROR:  Error installing sinatra:
[stderr]    rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

I have tried this in my appspec.yml file'

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.4.1
  - jruby-head
Before_install:  # For jruby-head to work.
  - gem install bundler
  - gem update bundler
```

any kind of help would be awesome thanks

and here is my version of appspec.yml before trying what i found up above

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /.
   destination: /var/www/html/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: app.rb
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: app.rb
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: app.rb
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "~> 2.3.0"
gem 'sinatra', '2.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeDeploy appspec doesn't need to support that option actually, the scripts for each lifecycle event will run with env ruby. If you want to run a particular version of ruby, probably you can change that to default ruby version in one of you scripts for one of the lifecycle event, like BeforeInstall.